# Same Cookie Name For Different Web Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, cookies, c#-4.0

I have two web applications running on the same server. I have session handler module which I have used in both application. The session handler sets session information in cookies by following way:

```
HttpCookie appCookie = new HttpCookie("sessionid");
appCookie.Value = sessionid;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(appCookie);
```

So both applications set cookie named sessionid. So one application cookie replace another. As both application running on same server so domain name is same. However I have tried to set the path for cookie but when I set the path like

```
appCookie.Path = "/localhost:64456/";
```

cookie doesn't set. I know I went wrong in setting cookie path. But couldn't figure it out.

Comment: That is not a path.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the [Domain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.domain(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
appCookie.Domain = "localhost:64456";
```

Alternatively, look at virtual applications in IIS, then you could have different paths like `/app1` and `/app2`.